# MARS (MIPS) error - Not a valid data segment address

Tags: assembly, mips

When I try to compile my program, I am getting the following errors from the .data section.

```
Error in C:\Users\chris\Documents\convert_to_asm_2.asm line 9 column 14: "120000" is not a valid data segment address
Error in C:\Users\chris\Documents\convert_to_asm_2.asm line 10 column 15: "120000" is not a valid data segment address
Error in C:\Users\chris\Documents\convert_to_asm_2.asm line 11 column 15: "120000" is not a valid data segment address
Error in C:\Users\chris\Documents\convert_to_asm_2.asm line 12 column 15: "120000" is not a valid data segment address
Error in C:\Users\chris\Documents\convert_to_asm_2.asm line 13 column 13: "120000" is not a valid data segment address
Error in C:\Users\chris\Documents\convert_to_asm_2.asm line 14 column 13: "120000" is not a valid data segment address
Assemble: operation completed with errors.
```

The lines that it is throwing errors on are:

```
.data
width: .word 0       #Error - Line 9
height: .word 0      #Error - Line 10
startX: .word 0      #Error - Line 11
startY: .word 0      #Error - Line 12
endX: .word 0        #Error - Line 13
endY: .word 0        #Error - Line 14
```

I removed the `0` from each of the `.word` lines, then the program compiles, but it throws an error on the `sw` command of the following code, which are the first lines of the `main:`

```
    li $v0,5
    syscall
    la $a0,width
    sw $v0,($a0)
```

Error is:

```
Error in C:\Users\chris\Documents\convert_to_asm_2.asm line 27: Runtime exception at 0x0000300c: address out of range 0xffffd4c0
```

Minimal Code to reproduce error:

```
.eqv true 1 # define true 1
.eqv false 0 # define false 0

.eqv MAX 40000 # 100 * 100 * 4 = 40000
.data
maze: .space MAX
wasHere: .space MAX
correctPath: .space MAX
width: .word 
height: .word 
startX: .word 
startY: .word 
endX: .word 
endY: .word 

.text
main:
    # we use $t0 for y
    # we use $t1 for x
    # we use $t2 for tempchar

    # scanf("%d%d", &width, &height);
    # scanf("%d", &width);
    li $v0,5
    syscall
    la $a0,width
    sw $v0,($a0)
    # scanf("%d", &height);
    li $v0,5
    syscall
    la $a0,height
    sw $v0,($a0)
    # for(y=0; y < height; y++)
    # {
    # for(x=0; x < width; x++)
    # {
    li $t0,0 # y = 0
```

Anybody have any ideas on what is going on and how to fix it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example that can be used to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Michael edited with code to reproduce the error

Comment: Unable to reproduce with Mars 4.5 on Windows 10.

Comment: My guess is that you've gone into Mars' Memory Configuration settings and selected "Compact, Data at Address 0", in which case it probably can't fit your 3 large arrays. I use the "Default" configuration.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: On SO we don't put edit "solved" in the title.  We post an answer; the site shows whether a question has an accepted answer or not.  If you want to post your own answer, go ahead, or @Michael: can repost that comment as an answer.